# Creating callbacks with blocks

Tags: objective-c, callback, objective-c-blocks

I'm new to Objective-C having come from the JavaScript world, and I'm trying to define a "callback" property on a class. In JavaScript land we're used to passing around functions willy-nilly, but it seems Objective-C isn't so lenient.

Here's how I tried to do it (trying to simplify things as much as possible):

```
@interface CallbackThing : NSObject
  @property (nonatomic) NSString *derpDerp;
  @property (nonatomic) SEL callback;
@end
```

Then later in another class....

```
CallbackThing *testCallbackThing = [CallbackThing alloc] init];
testCallbackThing.callback = @selector(methodInThisCLass);
```

Finally in another class...

```
if (self.testCallbackThing.callback != nil){
    [self.thatOtherClass performSelector:self.testCallbackThing.callback];
}
```

That works great! I was so proud of myself... Until...

**"warning: performSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown!"**

Trying to read up on things, and it seems that the new way to do things is to use blocks... But none of the examples I've looked at make much sense in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your specific use case is, but blocks are easy. First, declare your block type:

```
typedef void (^MyBlock)(NSArray*, NSString*);
```

Then you can set this as a property, like you did with SEL:

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) MyBlock block;
```

Then, you simply call the block, which executes it:

```
self.block(someArray, someString);
```

Comment: If he's not using arc, it should be retained rather than assigned, otherwise the block could have been released before it is called resulting in a crash.

Comment: @max_ ARC or not, blocks are ***always*** (and I cannot stress that always enough) copy.

Comment: @CodaFi: well, technically, in ARC, `strong` on a block type is the same as `copy`, so `strong` would also be correct in ARC

Comment: @newacct unless the block is cast to id, then the compiler doesn't copy it, but rather does a strong store of the block.  Big no-no.  It's always best to be explicit anyhow.

Comment: @codafi, that comment was from before mohabitar made the comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm surprised the typedef step was required. Strange that Objective-C wouldn't natively support a block as a property.